# how to add circles on top of each other in Flutter

Tags: android, flutter, dart, mobile, widget

what is the most reasonable and clean way to make a design like the one below?
I'm wondering how to make a design like this in accordance with the flutter clean design logic. Thanks in advance for your help.

[image]

I have tried circleAvatar widget inside stack

Comment: [`ClipOval`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ClipOval-class.html) is what you're looking for.

Comment: If you want to do it in simple way. Just export the background image and use stack or container background then create profile image circle and below text at the center.

Comment: Actually, I prefer it to be changeable in gradient colors in the background.

Comment: check `CustomPaint` widget

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to create the above style would be to export the image(preferably as SVG) and use Stack to create the above Widget.